# When i get the record from database the type is changes to JToken

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am storing a property Parameters of Type `Dictionary<string, object>` as type `jsonb`.

When i get the record from database the type is changes to `JToken`.

[image]

Here is the value in the database:
[image]

Here is the model class:

```cs
public sealed class ExecuteQueryTask
    {
        public ExecuteQueryTask();

        public Guid TaskId { get; set; }
        public Guid QueryId { get; set; }
        public Guid DatabaseId { get; set; }
        public Guid ServerId { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public ExecutionStatusEnum Status { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan TimeElapsed { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Error> Errors { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: _"When i get the record from database the type is changes to JToken."_ - and? `JToken` as everything in .NET inherits from `object`.

Comment: Is there any configuration i can add so i get the native value type

Comment: You get the native type already - a JSON object. `jsonb` is JSON content that can be an array, dictionary or array of dictionaries

Comment: What "native" value type? Arrays are not value types. "Even" strings are not value types.  `IDictionary<string, object>` means that you can have arbitrary nested JSON so you need something to represent that - `JToken` is such thing.

Comment: If you want access to the actual integers and strings, you'll have to use strongly typed objects. If you want to support arbitrary content though, it's probably better to use `JObject` instead of `IDictionary<string, object>`. JObject implements `IDictionary<string, JToken>` and `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` which means you can access all elements by name and index

Comment: The use of Parameters is to pass the values to sql query parameters here the type can be anything hence using object. Can you provide me with an example code or related implementation

Comment: _"Can you provide me with an example code or related implementation"_ - what example code? What implementation? What is actually wrong with current code? What is the actual question here?